# how to open an app from Mac from Xcode project (Cocoa App)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

Today I have created an `Cocoa Application` for the very first time . I want to create a simple App which will open an APP from my `Mac` , if the file not found it will show a `Link` in a `Label` to download the App. Here is my code below which I am struggling with .

```
  if let fileCheck = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: "/Applications/Mango.app") {
        if NSWorkspace.shared().open(fileCheck as URL) {
            print("url successfully opened")
        }
    } else {
      self.downloadLink.insertText("Invalid Path")
    }
```

**NSURL.fileURL(withPath: "/Applications/Mango.app")** giving me **Conditional Binding Must be Optional** , I don't know how to fix that. `And I am struggling with how to show a link on my Label either.` Any kind hearted Dev please help.

Answer (score 0):

got the solution by someone , I don't know why he deleted that !

```
   if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: "/Applications/Mango.app") {
       NSWorkspace.shared().open(NSURL(fileURLWithPath:   "/Applications/Mango.app") as URL)
    } else {
        downloadLink.isHidden = false
    }
```